# ascending sort without using arrays in java

Tags: java, sorting

This code has to enter 5 integers and then display them in ascending and descending orders without using arrays. But it gives me only the biggest number. How can i do it without arrays??

```
package assignment;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter a number", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
        String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter a number", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(b);
        String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter a number", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int number3 = Integer.parseInt(c);
        String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter a number", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int number4 = Integer.parseInt(d);
        String e = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter a number", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int number5 = Integer.parseInt(e);

        if (number1 > number2 && number1 > number3 && number1 > number4 && number1 > number5) {
            System.out.print(number1 + ",");
        } else if (number2 > number1 && number2 > number3 && number2 > number4 && number2 > number5) {
            System.out.print(number2 + ",");
        } else if (number3 > number1 && number3 > number2 && number3 > number4 && number3 > number5) {
            System.out.print(number3 + ",");
        } else if (number4 > number1 && number4 > number2 && number4 > number3 && number4 > number5) {
            System.out.print(number4 + ",");
        } else if (number5 > number1 && number5 > number2 && number5 > number3 && number5 > number4) {
            System.out.print(number5 + ",");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it say "without using arrays", or does it say "without using `Arrays`"?

Comment: no for loop? no bubble or any other type of sort?

Comment: ... use an ArrayList?

Comment: No arrays guys. That's how I'm asked to do it. :)

Comment: Can you use a `Set`? What about a `LinkedList`?

Comment: to do your homework?!!!!

Comment: Well, you're using else if logic, only one if statement would get executed ever.

Comment: You want a sorting network. http://jgamble.ripco.net/cgi-bin/nw.cgi?inputs=5&algorithm=best&output=macro

Comment: SWAP means if b < a then swap the values of a and b.

Comment: no Arrays, how about a priority queue?  or, keep iterating over your input boxes and each time you find the remaining maximum, set it to some impossible value that tells you it's been grabbed.

Comment: btw, figuring out your own homework will help more in the long run than coming here!

Comment: Call James Gosling to invent something special for you.

Comment: -1 to the teacher making you do this

Comment: Take it easy guys. Though there are lots of tutorials and explanations on sorting, there aren't really any for doing sorts outside of methods and using data stuctures, which he isn't allowed to use at the moment.

Comment: Thnks MarGar, the only helpful comment was yours :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly I couldn't really find much on sorting outside of arrays and lists so I will assist you.

Code:

```
  int temp;

for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++)
{
    if ( number2 < number1)
    {
       temp = number1;
       number1 = number2;
       number2 = temp;
    }

    if ( number3 < number2)
    {
       temp = number2;
       number2 = number3;
       number3 = temp;
    }

    if ( number4 < number3)
    {
       temp = number3;
       number3 = number4;
       number4 = temp;
    }

    if ( number5 < number4)
    {
       temp = number4;
       number4 = number5;
       number5 = temp;
    }
}

System.out.println( number1 + " " + number2 + " " + number3 + " " + number4 + " " + number5);
System.out.println( number5 + " " + number4 + " " + number3 + " " + number2 + " " + number1);
```

Sorting will get easier as you learn some of the algorithms and how they work. Until then, I hope this helps.

The basic idea is to check each pair and swap the values. You will need to do this multiple times in order to get the last value to the beginning of your list of values.

Comment: This seems more appropriate, doing it 118 times like the other answer suggests is nuts :P

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment Mar, your code works.

Comment: My answer was more of a joke. Though it would work if you took the time to write out all 120 permutations. This is obviously a more elegant answer.

Comment: Hey, if it works then it IS an answer! I thought it was funny :).

Answer (score 2):

Easy. It can be done in **120** lines.

```
if(number1>=number2 && number2>=number3 && number3>=number4 && number4>=number5)
    System.out.print(number1 + "," + number2 + "," + number3 + "," + number4 + "," + number5);
else if (number1>=number2 && number2>=number3 && number3>=number5 && number5>=number4)
    System.out.print(number1 + "," + number2 + "," + number3 + "," + number5 + "," + number4);
else if ...
```

Just do this 118 more times for every permutation of 5P5  :P

Brute force to the max.

Enjoy doing this with 10 integers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the logic you are using is correct.

I suppose the code for arranging 5 int variables in **decending order** will be

*Assume that the variables are **initialized** and **assigned***

```
int max;
int temp;
for(int i=1 ; i<=4 ; i++)
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        max=n1;
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        max=n2;
    }
    if(i==3)
    {
        max=n3;
    }
    if(i==4)
    {
        max=n4;
    }

    for(int j=i+1 ; j<=5 ; j++)
    {
        if(j<=2)
        {
            if(n2>max)
            {
                temp=n2;
                n2=max;
                max=temp;
            }
        }

        if(j<=3)
        {
            if(n3>max)
            {
                temp=n3;
                n3=max;
                max=temp;
            }
        }

        if(j<=4)
        {
            if(n4>max)
            {
                temp=n4;
                n4=max;
                max=temp;
            }
        }

        if(j<=5)
        {
            if(n5>max)
            {
                temp=n5;
                n5=max;
                max=temp;
            }
        }   

    }
    if(i==1)
    {
        n1=max;
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        n2=max;
    }
    if(i==3)
    {
        n3=max;
    }
    if(i==4)
    {
        n4=max;
    }
}
System.out.print(n1 + "," + n2 + "," + n3 + "," + n4 + "," + n5);
```

Well..I am basically using **Selection Sort** here.

Comment: `System.out.print(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);` will not work.

Comment: Be careful, it's easy to get a down vote, especially when your code doesn't work. +1 for an alternate solution.