# Java: ordering elements without use of array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have a homework where I'm supposed to prompt the user to enter five numbers and arrange them from min to max and since we didn't take arrays

I'm only left with Math.min & Math.max or if statement.

I wrote a code where the first, second and last number are always correct But I can't seem to figure out how to do the 3rd and 4th number

Here's an example:

```
    if (a <= b && a <= c && a <= d && a <= e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers in Ascending order "
                + a + " " +Math.min(Math.min(b, c), Math.min(d, e)) +
                " " + "?" +
                " " + "?" +
                " " +Math.max(Math.max(b, c), Math.max(d, e)));
    }
```

If you know any idea that might help me solve this task?

Comment: `java !== javascript`

Comment: What you have shown is not Javascript - Java and Javascript are completely different languages

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int a = 32;
    int b = 42;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 88;
    int e = 92901;
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 5) {
        int currentMin = findMin(a, b, c, d, e);

        // Printing smallest number yeat
        System.out.print(currentMin + " ");

        if (a == currentMin){
            a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        if (b == currentMin){
            b = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        if (c == currentMin){
            c = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        if (d == currentMin){
            d = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        if (e == currentMin){
            e = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

private static int findMin(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    int smallest = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, Math.min(c, Math.min(d, e))));
    return smallest;
}
```

Notice how I am using the Integer.MAX_VALUE to remove the smallest number yeat for example in the first iteration 2 will be returned which is equals to c now I have to make the code somehow to ignore c in the next iteration because it was already used if I was using the Integer object i could have set c to be null but int cannot be setted to null so what i can do is to set it to number so large that findMin function would never choose it again that's why I use MAX_VALUE

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use while statement

Comment: You can always call for this logic 5 times

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do it using **if**,**else if** statements then you will have to write one **if** statement and 119 **else if** statements i.e. number of ways in which 5 numbers can be arranged. 5!=120.

if you are allowed to use for loop check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104767/ascending-sort-without-using-arrays-in-java) link

Answer (score 0):

```
int aux;
if (b < a){
    aux = b; b = a; a = aux;
}
if (c < a){
    aux = c; c = b; b = a; a = aux;
}
else{
    if (c < b){
        aux = c; c = b; b = aux;
    }
}
...
```

I guess you get the idea, in the end `a` will be the smallest and `e` will be the biggest

For more information, since it looks like you're getting started to programming and sorting algorithms, this is called Insertion Sort (I believe). More information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible answer. Since loop and arrays cannot be used, much of the code is repetition. In the end a,b,c,d,e contain the values arranged from min to max. Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.*;

class SortFiveElements {

    //utility function
    //returns index as a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:4
    public static int find_min_index(int a,int b, int c,int d, int e, int min)
    {
        return a==min?1:(b==min?2:(c==min)?3:(d==min?4:5));
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int d = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int e = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        //temp is a temporary var to store the i-th value which may get replaced
        //smallest stores the min value among i-th to 5th element
        //idx stores the minimum value's index
        int temp,smallest,idx;

        //i=1,  i.e element 'a'
        //temp has value of 1st element that is a
        //find minimum among 5 elements in 'smallest', its index in 'idx'
        //then swap
        temp = a;
        smallest = Math.min(a,Math.min(b,Math.min(c,Math.min(d,e))));
        idx = find_min_index(a,b,c,d,e,smallest);
        a = smallest;
        if(idx==1)
            a=temp;
        else if(idx==2)
            b = temp;
        else if(idx==3)
            c = temp;
        else if(idx==4)
            d = temp;
        else
            e = temp;

        //i=2,  i.e element 'b'
        //temp has value of 2nd element that is b
        //find minimum among 4 elements in 'smallest', its index in 'idx'
        //NB: a already has the smallest value, so replace a with MAX_VALUE while finding index
        //then swap
        temp = b;
        smallest = Math.min(b,Math.min(c,Math.min(d,e)));
        idx = find_min_index(Integer.MAX_VALUE,b,c,d,e,smallest);
        b = smallest;
        if(idx==1)
            a=temp;
        else if(idx==2)
            b = temp;
        else if(idx==3)
            c = temp;
        else if(idx==4)
            d = temp;
        else
            e = temp;

        //repeat above process for 'c' and 'd'.
        //'e' will automatically fall in place
        temp = c;
        smallest = Math.min(c,Math.min(d,e));
        idx = find_min_index(Integer.MAX_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE,c,d,e,smallest);
        c = smallest;
        if(idx==1)
            a=temp;
        else if(idx==2)
            b = temp;
        else if(idx==3)
            c = temp;
        else if(idx==4)
            d = temp;
        else
            e = temp;

        temp = d;
        smallest = Math.min(d,e);
        idx = find_min_index(Integer.MAX_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                             Integer.MAX_VALUE,d,e,smallest);
        d = smallest;
        if(idx==1)
            a=temp;
        else if(idx==2)
            b = temp;
        else if(idx==3)
            c = temp;
        else if(idx==4)
            d = temp;
        else
            e = temp;

        //we have the values in sorted order in a,b,c,d,e
        System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d+" "+e);
    }
}
```